Functions $f$ satisfying $f(2x^2) = -2f(x^2)\ \forall \ x\in\mathbb{R}$
I got $f(0) = 0$ as $f(0) = -2f(0)$ and $f(2^nx) = (-2)^nf(x)$.
However I am unable to move further. Also I tried to prove discontinuity as follows.
Say $x_0$ is the smallest $x>0$ for which $f(x) = 0$ again then for all $x\in(0,x_0) ,\ f(x)>0$ or $f(x) <0$.
Say $\frac{x_0}{4} = k \neq 0  $ then $\frac{x_0}{2} = -2k$.
Clearly they lie on opposite sides of the $x$ axis which is a contradiction.
Any hints would be appreciated!

Are there any other constraints on $f(x)$?

There are no other constraints on f(x)

There are continuous solutions on $\Bbb{R}_{>0}$ such as $f(x)=2\sin(\pi\log_2x)$ Define $f(x)=0$ for $x\leq0$ and you're done.

Oh... would you be able to tell me where I have gone wrong in my proof?
Also would you be able to explain how you got this function?

You have only proved that there is no smallest positive solution to $f(x)=0$.

On $\Bbb{R}_{>0}$ your functional equation $f(ax)=bf(x)$ forces $f$ to be a periodic function of $\log(x)$. Then one continuous example to try is $f(x)=c\sin(d\log(x))$. Then it is quickly clear that $c=2$ and $d=\pi/\log(2)$ work. Your functional equation sets no requirements on $x<0$ whatsoever.

@Servaes I have a small follow up question... the absolute values in the function should be increasing right as $f(2^nx)=(−2)^nf(x)$ so wouldn't it be correct if the
function was $2xsin(\pi\log_{2}x)$ ?

@RishitGarg that's right.

When dealing with real numbers you can't just say "the smallest $x>0$ such that ...". Which is the smallest $x>0$ such that $x<2x$?

An example of a continuous solution is:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x\sin(\pi\log_2x)&\text{ if } x>0\\0&\text{ if }x\leq0\end{cases}.$$
There are of course uncountably many discontinuous solutions:

Map each coset of $\{2^n:\ n\in\Bbb{Z}\}$ in the multiplicative group $\Bbb{R}_{>0}$ to another such coset.
Map each $r\in\Bbb{R}_{<0}$ to an arbitrary value.
Map $0$ to $0$.

This yields a function satisfying your functional equation.

Anyone care to explain the downvote?

someone is messing with the votes...

@Servaes Add your comment to the answer, it will be more complete.

Strictly speaking, the "continuous" function given is nor defined for all real $x$ as the problem specifies.

@OscarLanzi You are correct, I was a bit sloppy. I have fixed the function to be defined for all real $x$.

@SigmaAlgebra Good suggestion, done.

oh wait, shouldn't the continuous example look like $f(x)=x\sin(\pi\log_{2}x)$ ?

@QuýNhân You are absolutely right, I've corrected this now.

I think you need to fix the part above as well, like $f$ is not periodic and I don't know what is $d$ in your $cd=\pi/\log2$

@QuýNhân I'll remove my attempt at an explanation, as I do not care to make precise the intuition behind the example.


$f(2x)=-2f(x) \hspace .5cm \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^+$

This is trivial and you saw it. It only works on $x\ge0$ though, as $x$ is the result of a squaring. Also trivial is the fact $f(0) = 0$, and that $f$ changes signs an infinite number of times

$f(x) = 0 \hspace .5cm \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ is a solution.

your condition leads us to not be able to say anything on $f(x)$ for strictly negative $x$. We need to assume another property (oddness, evenness...) to be able to say anything about the negative side.

As shown by others, $f(x)=x\sin(\pi\log_2x)$ is a valid continuous solution on $\mathbb{R}^+$, and we can make it valid on $\mathbb{R}$ by replacing $\log_2(x)$ with $\log_2(|x|)$


